# How to simulate "live" user session without logging-in repeating

Tags: jmeter

I have a quite large project for performance test with front and back-end. I need to simulate real user behaviour with straight forward distribution requirements. So only 10% of my front-end virtual users should execute logging-in, rest of them should be cashed. My guess is to use regular extractor to get sessionID from HTTP request after user login and to put it somehow to all my further samplers to simulate user session cashe. 
The question is how can I put this sessionID to my next HTTP request to simulate live user session without log-in?
Other fitable solution can be discussed as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can send sessionID via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). Just add one manager to each request in which you wanna send sessionID,then add header which will store the value, give it name and value and you are good.

[image: HTTP Header Manager scrennshot]